# Is there an easy way to extract tensor by viewing the elements as indices?

Tags: tensor

The input tensor shape as below

```
input = 
[[ 0  0  1  2]
 [ 0  3  4  5]
 [ 0  6  7  8]
 [ 1  9 10 11]
 [ 1 12 13 14]
 [ 1 15 16 17]
 [ 1 18 19 20]
 [ 1 21 22 23]
 [ 1 24 25 26]
 [ 1 27 28 29]
 [ 1 30 31 32]
 [ 2 33 34 35]
 [ 2 36 37 38]
 [ 2 39 40 41]]
```

And I want to extract block-wise elements according to the first element of each row(like:0,1,2), does anyone help me with it, THANKS!
If there are off-the-shelf function would be great.

Comment: What library are you using? It may help answerers if you can give more context to the question. I'm not sure what the block-wise elements are supposed to be.

Comment: Hi, its so nice to get reply from you, thanks. I was using numpy to create the matrix, pure python.  The 'block-wise' elements here I mean the rows with same first element(I probably made you all misunderstood in the question asking), for example above, the first three rows which first elements is 0, and followed by 8 rows which first elements with 1, and so on. 
Because I dont know how many row of each 'block', so it is become bit tricky for me.

Comment: Once you have grouped the rows, what would you do with them? What would the tensors look like in the final result?